# Mapbox default compassView when repositioned gives weird outcome

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapbox

I have a situation where I have to reposition the map box compass view to a different location. The compassView is now rotating when I rotate the map taking some other point as its(compassView) axis and gives me a weird outcome. Screenshot is attached, the black mapBox default compass icon is rotating, refer the screenshots. Is this a MapBox sdk bug? if so, are there any work around? And tweaks? I am confused. Expert advices needed. Thanks in advance.

[image: First Image][image: Second Image][image: Third Image]

Comment: I have faced the same scenario. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey I found another method where I will get the same result of the compass in the map box. I've placed a button and then

```
func mapViewRegionIsChanging(_ mapView: MGLMapView) {
    compassViewUpdate(direction: Double(bearing))
```

inside compassViewUpdate method

```
func compassViewUpdate(direction:Double) {

    self.compassButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-direction.degreesToRadians))
}
```

@Sarang here is a work around. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

A built-in approach that's available in the Mapbox iOS SDK. Using these methods
to move the compass will avoid the distortion caused by `.frame` and `.center`
changes.

**Generally Changing the CompassView Location**

```swift
mapView.compassViewPosition = .bottomLeft
mapView.compassViewPosition = .bottomRight
mapView.compassViewPosition = .topLeft
mapView.compassViewPosition = .topRight
```

Use `compassViewPosition` to get the compass generally where you want it on the
screen.

**Fine Tuning the CompassView Location**

```
mapView.compassViewMargins = CGPoint(x: 64, y: 16)
```

*Default x, y = 8, 8*

The margin is to the outside/along the border of the view. So for `.bottomLeft`
the compass view will move 56 right and 8 up versus `.topRight` where the
compass will move 56 left and 8 down.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the compassView.center instead of changing its origin or frame. I am guessing it has approximately 40 pixels width x height, and I changed to bottom left using the following:

```
    let centerCalc = CGRect(x: 5, y: frame.height - 45, width: 40, height: 40)
    compassView.center = CGPoint(x: centerCalc.midX, y: centerCalc.midY)
```

It should work!