# Mapbox Swift compass visibilty property

Tags: swift, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-ios

Hi all I am trying to get the compass to disappear off my map and have hit a brick wall. Below is my map initialization function and I'm not sure what the variable is. I have tried `mapView.compassEnabled == false`, `mapView.compassView = nil` and a few other things that I have found to no avail.

I appreciate any help!

```
  @objc func initMap() {
    if mapView != nil {
      print("Attempting to init map that is already initialized, returning")
      return
    }

    mapView = NavigationMapView(frame: UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window!!.bounds, // TODO: Set frame from react
      styleURL: NSURL(string: "mapbox://styles/paway/ckcp7w04x03by1iqi1t26uilu") as URL?)
    guard let mapView = self.mapView else { return }

    mapView.zoomLevel = 2
    mapView.delegate = self
    mapView.locationManager.setDistanceFilter?(6)
    PWLocationManager.shared.delegate = self
    mapView.setCenter(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.0902, longitude: -95.7129), animated: false)
    mapView.navigationMapViewDelegate = self

    switch cameraMode {
    case "overview":
      mapCameraState = .overviewMode
      mapView.userTrackingMode = .followWithHeading
    case "followHeading":
      mapCameraState = .followMode
      mapView.userTrackingMode = .followWithHeading
    default:
      mapView.userTrackingMode = .none
    }
    
    mapView.isPitchEnabled = true
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    self.addSubview(mapView)
    
    addMapTapRecognizer()
    addObservers()
  }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Updated answer**

This only works if you have a component that is on top of your map. IF you have just a plain map I would try using negative margins to push the compass out of view.

I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57560116/13639051

I added :

`mapView.compassViewPosition = .bottomLeft`

`mapView.compassViewMargins = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)`

which hides the compass behind a bottom toast that is consistently across the project.